# How to perform a conditional count in a Rails active record query?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

In a Rails 3.2 app I'm trying to construct a query that will return an array with two calculated counts. The app has three models: a User has many Events, and a Location has many Events. I need to return an array for a user that contains the number of events they have at each location, as well as the number of active events.

e.g., `[#<Location id: 1, name: "Location Name", total_events_count: 4, active_event_count: 4>]>`

I can get the total_event_count

```
user = User.find(params[:id])
user.locations
  .select("locations.id, locations.name, count(events.id) AS total_events_count")
  .joins(:events)
  .group("locations.id")
```

Given that my Event model has a string `status` field that can take a value `active`, how would I also include an active_events_count in this query?

**EDIT**

After some useful suggestions from xdazz and mu, I'm still struggling with this. My problem appears to be that the count is counting all events, rather than events that belong to the location AND the user.

I'm going to try to rephrase my question, hopefully someone can help me understand this.

Events belong to both a User and a Location (i.e. `User has_many :locations, through: :events`)

Events have several fields, including `status` (a string) and `participants` (an integer).

In a User show view, I'm trying to generate a list of a User's locations. For each location, I want to display a "success rate". The success rate is the total number of a User;s events with participants, divided by the total number of that User's events. i.e., if User1 has 4 events at LocationA, but only two of those events had participants, User1's success rate at LocationA is 0.5 (or 50%).

The way I though to achieve this is via a select query that also includes calculated counts for `total_events_count` and `successful_events_count`. (there may be a better way?)

So I do something like:

```
user = User.find(params[:id])
user.locations
  .select("locations.id, locations.name, count(events.id) AS total_events_count, sum(case events.marked when NOT 0 then 1 else 0 end) AS successful_events_count")
  .joins(:events)
  .group("locations.id")
```

This is returning an array with the correct keys, but the values are not correct. I am getting the total number of all events (and all successful events) for that location, not just a count of those events that belong to the current user.

I have been looking at this problem for so long that I'm getting myself very confused. Would be very grateful for a fresh perspective and ideas!!

**EDIT2**

After a break and fresh eyes, I have managed to get the result I need using the following code. It seems quite convoluted. If there is a better way, please let me know. Otherwise I will tidy up this question in case anyone else runs into the same problem.

```
class User
def location_ratings
  events = self.events
  successful_events = events.where('events.participants > 0')
  user_events_by_location = Event.
    select("events.location_id AS l_id, count(events.id) AS location_event_count").
    where( id: events.pluck(:id) ).
    group("l_id").
    to_sql
  user_successful_events_by_location = Event.
    select("events.location_id AS l_id, count(events.id) AS location_successful_events_count").
    where( id: successful_events.pluck(:id) ).
    group("l_id").
    to_sql
  Location.
    joins("JOIN (#{user_events_by_location}) AS user_events ON user_events.l_id = location.id").
    joins("JOIN (#{user_successful_events_by_location}) AS successful_user_events ON successful_user_events.l_id = location.id").
    select('location.id, location.name, user_events.location_events_count, successful_user_events.location_successful_events_count').
    order("user_events.location_events_count DESC")
end
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `sum(events.marked='active')` to get it:

```
user.locations
  .select("locations.id, locations.name, count(events.id) AS total_events_count, sum(events.marked='active') AS marked_event_count")
  .joins(:events)
  .group("locations.id")
```

***Update:***

If you are using postgresql, then you have to case boolean to int before using `SUM` function.

```
user.locations
  .select("locations.id, locations.name, count(events.id) AS total_events_count, sum((events.marked='active')::int) AS marked_event_count")
  .joins(:events)
  .group("locations.id")
```

Comment: thanks xdazz, I'm getting `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  function sum(boolean) does not exist`. I've also edited my question slightly. The status field is not a boolean. I actually need to perform a conditional count based on the value of a string. Appreciate any ideas you may have. Thanks!

Comment: @AndyHarvey See my updated answer, postgresql is a bit different with mysql.

Comment: Why not a simple `sum(case events.marked when 'active' then 1 else 0 end)`? That sort of thing works everywhere.

Comment: thanks, these are both useful pieces of advice. However, I seem to be going round in circles with this, and I suspect I'm confused about what is included in the count. I've updated my question, and would really appreciate your help as I try to understand this.